# Share web link from ios using FBShareDialog OR SLComposeViewController not fetching image from web link

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sharing web link using FBShareDialog and also shared SLComposeViewController, and web link is hosted on my server only and on that web page all facebook meta tags are set correctly as below:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID">
    <meta property="og:url" content="[http://example.com/share/?ODk0][1]">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta property="og:title" content="I Created This With App - The Office">
    <meta property="og:description" content="NOOOO!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/upload/large/5971ed74a0e52.png">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="420">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My App Name">
```

When I share the below link 
http://example.com/share/?ODk0

directly from the facebook then it fetched the image mentioned in og:image meta tag and all working.. 
And when I try to test that link to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ then also it shows all is correct.

BUT when I share this link from my app using below code:

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent.init()
            content.contentURL = URL.init(string: "http://example.com/share/?ODk0")
            let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog.init()
            dialog.fromViewController = parentViewController
            dialog.shareContent = content
            dialog.mode = .shareSheet
            dialog.show()
```

Then it will opens share dialog and then it fetch the og:image and shows on share dialog, and then I do POST on facebook. And then I go to facebook it doesn't shows that image. This is the issue I am facing since last 2 weeks. I had upgraded Facebook sdk, and checked all upgradation but no luck.

Is there anyone can help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let shareURL = String.init(format: "%@f-%@", SHAREURL, base64!)
        let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = NSURL(string: shareURL)! as URL
        print("facebook content url :\(content.contentURL)")
        let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
        dialog.fromViewController = self
        dialog.shareContent = content
        dialog.delegate = self
        dialog.mode = .feedWeb
        if dialog.canShow() {
            dialog.show()
        }
```

Using above code it worked for me finally.